# Looking for a regression model or other statistics models for competitions

Tags: regression, logistic, biostatistics

We have botanical data and need to analyze this sort of scenario, in terms of students for the simplicity of explanation:

We have a series of competitions or trials, each one involves two individuals at a time - each trial has two new individuals. We test for a binary score - win or lose - in the test, and want to see if attributes (variables) of the individuals affect this result. Those variables are a mix of numeric ones such as age etc., and categorical ones, such as the school the each individual comes from. So the trials are independent among them, but naturally the result of each trial depends not only on the winner's attributes but also on his opponent's.

We could think of any simpler mixed effect and/or nested logistic model.

Do you have any suggestions?

Is it possible to to a regression analysis on this? Or any other statistics?

Someone suggested Bayesian inference due to the categorical variables we have some prior data on, but we prefer not to use Bayesian methods. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think mixed-effects logistic regression is enough. Two individuals as observations (level-1) are nested within each trial (level-2). You can add some individual's characteristics to explain the probability to win. It is reasonable to set some random effects to account for the correlation of two individuals within a trial.

If you are more interested in "population-averaged" effects, you may use generalized estimation equations (GEE) to estimate the model.

Of course, you can also try other link functions for the generalized linear mixed model (GLMM), e.g. probit function or complementary-log-log function.