# How to make a regression model for a relation looking like a step function ? Why can't I get an output for recursive partitioning done below?

Tags: regression, cart, linear, rpart, recursive-model

I'm working on a [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_9-PiwjCiRpXzVUOXFQQk9uNVE/view?usp=sharing) to describe the relationship
between length and age of bluegill fish and the linear model based plot looks like this:

[image: Scatterplot]

I hence tried using recursive partitioning algorithm as answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61654/looking-for-a-regression-model-or-other-statistics-models-for-competitions) by [Matthew Drury](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/74500/matthew-drury).

I tried the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(x=length, y= age)
tree <- rpart(y ~ x, data=df)
summary(fish)

plot_tree <- function(tree, x, y) {
s <- seq(50, 200, by=1)
plot(x, y)
lines(s, predict(tree, data.frame(x=s)))
}
plot_tree(tree, age, length)
```

With this, I get the following output:[image]
 That is,I don't get the joining curve.I really can't figure out what is wrong with not getting a line when all the code ran without an error.

1) Knowing why I can't get a line by 'lines' for this rpart would really help me.

2) If not, please suggest me any other method to fit a model for this data.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding the step function bit mentioned in the title, that seems to be related to isotonic regression. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression

Comment: Thanks, seems relevant! I tried isotonic model using bivisio function in library(Iso) the R-code:
 
   y<-as.matrix(fish[c(1,2),])
    biviso(y, w = NULL, eps = NULL, eps2 = 1e-9, ncycle = 50000,
    fatal = TRUE, warn = TRUE)
I obtained matrix of the same dimensions as y containing the corresponding isotonic values. How do I construct the model from these isotonic values? Any help please?
  
       [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1 64.5
[2,]    1 64.5

Comment: You have a discrete age variable, but the relationship between E(Age|Length) and Length is not actually a step function. (It's possible you may want your fitted model to return a discrete predicted age though, rather than an expected age; you should make that explicit, because the term regression usually suggests a model for the expected value)

Comment: @BharatRamAmmu, you could also consider piecewise linear regression while supressing the slope, which would create a step function as your regression equation and is not restricted to being monotone, as in isotonic regression.

Comment: @Glen_b that is a great insight, I will re-consider my model