# Statistical significance test for duels

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, p-value

I have a data series that consists of a series of duels among combatants. Suppose there are four combatants, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, then my data can be denoted $((a, b), (b, a), (d, c), (c, b), (d, a), \ldots)$, where the first element of each tuple denotes the duel's winner.

I have calculated some descriptive statistics using this data; $a$ wins 70% of the time, $b$ wins 20% of the time, $c$ 50% of the time, and so on. How do I compute confidence intervals for these win ratios? I.e., I want to know what the probability is that my results are due to chance.

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61654/looking-for-a-regression-model-or-other-statistics-models-for-competitions   or   [tag:bradley-terry-model]

Comment: To complicated. I need an explanation with an example.

Comment: What is your sample size? Can you share (a link to) your data, or some mock-up?

Comment: My data is as described in the question. Sample size is in the hundreds.